# Object interface with condition in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In index.ts I declare an object with one optional prop and in index.d.ts I assign an interface to this object but typescript doesn't seem to see this assignment and warns that this property does not exist on this type.

What is the proper way to add a type to the Obj object?

```
// index.ts
import a from './a'
import b from './b'

const Obj = {
  a, b
}

if (condition){
  Obj.log = function(){} // Typescript: log does not exist on type {...}
}


// index.d.ts
declare interface IObj {
  log (any): void;
}

declare const Obj: IObj;
```

Comment: Why do you use a separate definition file ? Why not just type `Obj` directly as `{ a: typeof import ('./a'), b: typeof import ('./b'), log?: () => void ` ?

Comment: Just try to keep things separately and the docs recommend this way. There should be no difference, right?

Comment: Not sure what docs recommend doing this, could you please share the link. I would actually expect ts to use a definition file for the code written in TS, if the original ts is part of the build.

Comment: So it's not docs but some handbook where I read it https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html . Also the inline declaration as you suggested does work, but I'd like to make it work with .d.ts, just for the sake of learning for the future.

Comment: But the first line of that is very explicit: 'You can tell TypeScript that you are trying to describe **code that exists elsewhere**'

Comment: Yes, "using the declare keyword", and that's what I'm doing with `declare const Obj: IObj;`, but for some reason it's not applying to `const Obj` in index.ts. Is there any config needed for this to work or some import/export?